# Segmentation Fault when running Tensorflow Lite Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am running Tensorflow Lite on my Raspberry Pi 3b+ with a custom object detection mode. I have tested it on a Google COCO dataset and it works wonderfully but when I test it on my custom trained model it does not work despite the model passing TfLite Model Maker evaluation. When I run it the only error I get in my message is "Segmentation fault". How can I fix this?

I am not able to upload my model to Stackoverflow but just some info about it. It is only detecting one object, It is **Not** quantized, it is trained based off the efficientdet_lite1 mode, and I trained it using the official Tensorflow Lite Model Maker Google Colab.

Here is the code used to interpret the model on my Pi.

```
ed=True)
parser.add_argument('--graph', help='Name of the .tflite file, if different than detect.tflite',
                    default='detect.tflite')
parser.add_argument('--labels', help='Name of the labelmap file, if different than labelmap.txt',
                    default='labelmap.txt')
parser.add_argument('--threshold', help='Minimum confidence threshold for displaying detected objects',
                    default=0.5)
parser.add_argument('--resolution', help='Desired webcam resolution in WxH. If the webcam does not support the resolution entered, errors may occur.',
                    default='1280x720')
parser.add_argument('--edgetpu', help='Use Coral Edge TPU Accelerator to speed up detection',
                    action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

MODEL_NAME = args.modeldir
GRAPH_NAME = args.graph
LABELMAP_NAME = args.labels
min_conf_threshold = float(args.threshold)
resW, resH = args.resolution.split('x')
imW, imH = int(resW), int(resH)
use_TPU = args.edgetpu

# Import TensorFlow libraries
# If tflite_runtime is installed, import interpreter from tflite_runtime, else import from regular tensorflow
# If using Coral Edge TPU, import the load_delegate library
pkg = importlib.util.find_spec('tflite_runtime')
if pkg:
    from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter
    if use_TPU:
        from tflite_runtime.interpreter import load_delegate
else:
    from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter
    if use_TPU:
        from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import load_delegate

# If using Edge TPU, assign filename for Edge TPU model
if use_TPU:
    # If user has specified the name of the .tflite file, use that name, otherwise use default 'edgetpu.tflite'
    if (GRAPH_NAME == 'detect.tflite'):
        GRAPH_NAME = 'edgetpu.tflite'       

# Get path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to .tflite file, which contains the model that is used for object detection
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,GRAPH_NAME)

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,LABELMAP_NAME)

# Load the label map
with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:
    labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

# Have to do a weird fix for label map if using the COCO "starter model" from
# https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview
# First label is '???', which has to be removed.
if labels[0] == '???':
    del(labels[0])

# Load the Tensorflow Lite model.
# If using Edge TPU, use special load_delegate argument
if use_TPU:
    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT,
                              experimental_delegates=[load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1.0')])
    print(PATH_TO_CKPT)
else:
    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT)

interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get model details
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]

floating_model = (input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32)

input_mean = 127.5
input_std = 127.5

# Initialize frame rate calculation
frame_rate_calc = 1
freq = cv2.getTickFrequency()

# Initialize video stream
videostream = VideoStream(resolution=(imW,imH),framerate=30).start()
time.sleep(1)

#for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):
while True:

    # Start timer (for calculating frame rate)
    t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

    # Grab frame from video stream
    frame1 = videostream.read()

    # Acquire frame and resize to expected shape [1xHxWx3]
    frame = frame1.copy()
    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_rgb, (width, height))
    input_data = np.expand_dims(frame_resized, axis=0)

    # Normalize pixel values if using a floating model (i.e. if model is non-quantized)
    if floating_model:
        input_data = (np.float32(input_data) - input_mean) / input_std

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'],input_data)
    interpreter.invoke()

    # Retrieve detection results
    boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0] # Bounding box coordinates of detected objects
    classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0] # Class index of detected objects
    scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])[0] # Confidence of detected objects
    #num = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])[0]  # Total number of detected objects (inaccurate and not needed)

    # Loop over all detections and draw detection box if confidence is above minimum threshold
    for i in range(len(scores)):
        if ((scores[i] > min_conf_threshold) and (scores[i] <= 1.0)):

            # Get bounding box coordinates and draw box
            # Interpreter can return coordinates that are outside of image dimensions, need to force them to be within image using max() and min()
            ymin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][0] * imH)))
            xmin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][1] * imW)))
            ymax = int(min(imH,(boxes[i][2] * imH)))
            xmax = int(min(imW,(boxes[i][3] * imW)))
            
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax), (10, 255, 0), 2)

            # Draw label
            object_name = labels[int(classes[i])] # Look up object name from "labels" array using class index
            label = '%s: %d%%' % (object_name, int(scores[i]*100)) # Example: 'person: 72%'
            labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, 2) # Get font size
            label_ymin = max(ymin, labelSize[1] + 10) # Make sure not to draw label too close to top of window
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, label_ymin-labelSize[1]-10), (xmin+labelSize[0], label_ymin+baseLine-10), (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED) # Draw white box to put label text in
            cv2.putText(frame, label, (xmin, label_ymin-7), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 0), 2) # Draw label text

    # Draw framerate in corner of frame
    cv2.putText(frame,'FPS: {0:.2f}'.format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    # Calculate framerate
    t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (t2-t1)/freq
    frame_rate_calc= 1/time1

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Clean up
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
videostream.stop()
```

Comment: can you add some debug, print, something so we can at least know which call is causing the segfault ?

Comment: Hey Ker2x, thanks for the response. I am not quite sure how to debug my code on my Pi and dont understand where you would like me to add prints. Is there anyway you can clarify a bit?

Comment: When does it crash ? what line ? run it with a debugger or use some print here and there to know where it is in the code when it crash

Comment: @ker2x Put some prints around my code. Last print around line 120-130 where it says 
```
# Load the label map
with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:
    labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```
After this nothing else is printed desipte having some print statements in the code

Edit: I added "???" to my label map and it got to around line 135 where it says
```
# Load the label map
with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:
    labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```
But does not go any further than this. Maybe this is a problem with me loading my model?

Comment: That formatting ended up weird lmk if you need it to be changed.

Comment: are you using a tpu ?

Comment: No I am not. Just my Pi

Comment: @ker2x Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an opportunity to execute your lite model on x86 system? Also it will come in handy if you find out what exact operation (inference step or any other) causes segfault.